# How to manage and reload multiple QuickFIX/J sessions independently?

Tags: quickfixj

I can configure multiple sessions in a single QuickFIX/J settings file and then start them all with a single `SocketInitiator`. But I would like to be able to modify the configuration of one or more sessions and then restart just those sessions without affecting any others.

I could do this by having multiple settings files and using one `SocketInitiator` per session. But it seems as though QuickFIX/J is not intended to be used this way. Would it cause me any problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is perfectly fine to start up an `Initiator` per session. It is a matter of taste. In any case: having a separate `Initiator` per session is independent and will not affect the other sessions.

If you want to follow the approach with a single `Initiator` then you could try to add/remove sessions dynamically via `createDynamicSession()`/`removeDynamicSession()`. There still is some manual work though.

1. Find the `Session` that you want to reload. `logout()` and `close()` it.
2. Call `removeDynamicSession()` for that `Session`.
3. Get the settings for the `SessionID` that you want to reload from the running `Initiator`. Remove these from the running `Initiator` via `removeSetting()`.
4. Then reload the settings from the settings file for the needed `Session` and put them to the settings of the `Initiator`.
5. Then call `createDynamicSession()` for the `SessionID`

Comment: Hi @ChristophJohn, thanks so much. I'll give it a try with one initiator per session to start with.