# QuickfixJ - better approach to create socketInitiator

Tags: quickfixj

We are developing Web version of initiator where we are taking the session ID- beginString,compIds from user . Then creating initiator.
In such case, what will be best approach :

1. Create and start new initiator everytime.
   --> in this case, if one is already connected, the second one will get disconnected and keep logging on which can be avoided by implementing the Application Extrended with logon as false. In such case, the initiator still remains in memory.  Will it not hamper memory of application now ?
2. Create only one socketinitiator per session, start once and logon multiple times - in such case, when users parallel start the connection, then both get logged for seconds then disconnect again.
   Do we need to.implement threading in this case ?

Let us know the better approach h

Comment: Have a look at adding sessions dynamically.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61623972/4962355